# Should a ClassLoader be able to resolve and load a class from a different package?

Tags: java, groovy, package, jenkins, classloader

Using the example given in the [documentation for ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) I am able to load a class which is in the same package as `${it}`:

```
ClassLoader cl = it.class.getClassLoader()
def builder = cl.loadClass("hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.ContentBuilder", true).newInstance()
```

But when I try to load from a different package like this:

```
def logParserParser = cl.loadClass("hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserParser", true).newInstance()
```

I get the error:

`Exception: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.logparser.LogParserParser`.

How can I load a class from a different package?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to make a work around to fix my specific problem.  It would be a lot nicer if the class would just resolve.  See my answer to another of my questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736780/288341).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the ClassLoader has been setup.  These type of errors usually occur when the class you want uses a class which is not available. i.e. the class itself is available.  What is the exact error message?

Comment: I updated my question with the exact error.  I can navigate to the class with file browser, so I know it is there.  The class does its job in Jenkins in a web browser too, I'm just trying to access it so I can get its output without going through a web browser.

Comment: You can also get this error if the class previously failed to load e.g. the static block threw an error, however the true cause isn't kept.

Answer (score 0):

What you attempt should work, I think.

Could it be an issue that the LogParserParser does not have a public no-args constructor?

Also, you might try running your test JVM with -XX:+TraceClassLoading to get better idea on what the classloader attempts to do.