# How to display Parsed Console Output of Log Parser Plugin in email-ext plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, logparser, email-ext

Email-ext plugin provides build.getLog(100) method to display console output. Is there a similar method to display Parsed Console Output logs ?

Comment: Did you see this question [Send parsed console output in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719902/send-parsed-console-output-in-email)?

Comment: Yes, I initially asked my question in that thread but it was deleted by Bill the Lizard♦ Dec 20 '12 at 4:21

Answer (score 0):

Write this line into "Default Content" of the mail:

Parsed console output link: ${BUILD_URL}parsed_console/