# Read Jenkins build console output and set email content

Tags: groovy, jenkins, email-ext

I have certain errors which I set in my code, which should add corresponding error messages to the email content of the final build email.

I was thinking of printing something such as ("EMAIL CONTENT ERROR: _______") to the console, reading through it (in a pre-send groovy script?), and adding corresponding error messages for each error found.

I was thinking of using a pre-send groovy script, setting the mimeMessage object(was reading jenkins email-ext documentation). Would this be viable?

Also, I have never used groovy before, so pointers to how to approach this would be extremely helpful(or a link to where i can find an implementation of something with a similar idea of reading console). Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check attaching "Build Log" This would highlight all the process of build process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar concept to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719902/send-parsed-console-output-in-email).  The technique there was to use the [log parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) to scan the console output for you, and then use groovy to add all the errors into an email.

This is generally a pretty good idea because it also means that you can view the same set of highlighted errors from jenkins itself, rather than just the email.

There are a couple of ways this is different from your setup, the main points are:

1. Yes, write errors directly to the console in a known format
2. Set the log parser up with regular expressions that find your error format
3. Instead of a pre-send script, in this case you would use a groovy template for your email generation
4. The template reads the error list from the console parser and adds them to your email.  Each one is a link that links back to the jenkins console output.